# Scalar `new T` vs array `new T[1]`

Tags: c++, new-operator

We recently discovery that some code was using `new T[1]` systematically (properly matched to `delete[]`), and I'm wondering if this is harmless, or there are some downsides in the generated code (in space or time/performance). Of course, this was hidden behind layers of functions and macros, but that's beside the point.

Logically, it appears to me that both are similar, but are they?

Are compilers allowed to turn this code (using a literal 1, not a variable, but via  functions layers, that `1` turns into an argument variable 2 or 3 times before reaching the code using thus `new T[n]`) into a scalar `new T`?

Any other considerations/things to know about the difference between these two?

Comment: No because delete[] would then be undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'd say yes, because of the "as-if" rule, provided it also changes `delete[]` to `delete`, of course. Nice question.

Comment: @RichardCritten Makes sense. Compiler unlikely to know where\when the `delete[]` takes place, so changing the `new T[1]` into `new T` could lead to undefined behavior. But on the main questions? Are they semantically identical? No downside(s) or one versus the other?

Comment: On my platform, `new` and `new[]` and `malloc` each manage an independent heap.  Trying to `delete`, `delete[]`, or `free` across heaps will terminate the application.  In such a case, that might be considered a downside.

Comment: Ok. I guess I shouldn't have included the _Are compilers allowed..._ part, as people fixate on that, rather than the part I cared about. My mistake.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think you are getting it backwards.  Compilers don't care about undefined behavior when optimizing.

Comment: @L.F. I never claimed they did.  How can the compiler inspect all the translation units in the program to modify all the necessary deletes?

Comment: What does "allowed to turn this code into" mean? The compiler makes the program act how the abstract machine acts. The abstract things in terms of which the state of the machine is described are irrelevant to the implementation. It makes no sense to talk about a "a scalar new T" existing in the implementation. If you just mean something like, what sort of difference would there typically be to generated code, please just say what you mean. Because "turning into" is attached to some notions that you haven't explained & is not obviously saying that or anything else.

Comment: @RichardCritten It doesn't need to modify the deletes.  The compiler can use whatever black magic to compile the code.

Comment: Do what you want with that info: with `new T` the implementation must allocate exactly `sizeof T` bytes, although with `new T[1]` it is free to allocate as much storage as it wants. source: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#15.sentence-2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If `T` doesn't have trivial destructor, then for usual compiler implementations, `new T[1]` has an overhead compared to `new T`. The array version will allocate a little bit larger memory area, to store the number of elements, so at `delete[]`, it knows how many destructors must be called.

So, it has an overhead:

- a little bit larger memory area must be allocated
- `delete[]` will be a little bit slower, as it needs a loop to call the destructors, instead calling a simple destructor (here, the difference is the loop overhead)

---

Check out this program:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

enum Tag { tag };

char buffer[128];

void *operator new(size_t size, Tag) {
    std::cout<<"single: "<<size<<"\n";
    return buffer;
}
void *operator new[](size_t size, Tag) {
    std::cout<<"array: "<<size<<"\n";
    return buffer;
}

struct A {
    int value;
};

struct B {
    int value;

    ~B() {}
};

int main() {
    new(tag) A;
    new(tag) A[1];
    new(tag) B;
    new(tag) B[1];
}
```

On my machine, it prints:

```
single: 4
array: 4
single: 4
array: 12
```

Because `B` has a non-trivial destructor, the compiler allocates extra 8 bytes to store the number of elements (because it is 64-bit compilation, it needs 8 extra bytes to do this) for the array version. As `A` does trivial destructor, the array version of `A` doesn't need this extra space.

---

Note: as Deduplicator comments, there is a slight performance advantage of using the array version, if the destructor is virtual: at `delete[]`, the compiler doesn't have to call the destructor virtually, because it knows that the type is `T`. Here's a simple case to demonstrate this:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};

void fn_single(Foo *f) {
    delete f;
}

void fn_array(Foo *f) {
    delete[] f;
}
```

Clang optimizes this case, but GCC doesn't: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eF2XBx).

For `fn_single`, clang emits a `nullptr` check, then calls the `destructor+operator delete` function virtually. It must do this way, as `f` can point to a derived type, which has a non-empty destructor.

For `fn_array`, clang emits a `nullptr` check, and then calls straight to `operator delete`, without calling the destructor, as it is empty. Here, the compiler knows that `f` actually points to an array of `Foo` objects, it cannot be a derived type, hence it can omit the calls to empty destructors.

Comment: Thanks. Insightful. In this case, the Dtor is non-trivial (but empty), and that code is generated (by GSoap). So I have my answer.

Comment: An interesting tid-bit is that the compiler always knows the most derived type for array-delete, thus won't call the dtor virtually. Doesn't quite balance the extra bookkeeping though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: that's a nice observation, thanks! I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Note that in my case, the destructors are empty, but non-trivial (I believe), since GSoap-generated types can contain std::vector members, so this particular Clang optimization does not apply, if I understand correctly (plus we use GCC, INTEL, and MSVC compilers, not Clang ATM)

Comment: @ddevienne: this example doesn't apply. But optimizing the virtual call to a non-virtual one can apply (if your destructor is virtual). It should not matter too much in your case, though (and maybe non-clang compilers doesn't do this optimization anyway). Supposedly a `std::vector` destructor call is much expensive (freeing the block), than a virtual call.

Answer (score 9):

No, the compiler is not allowed to replace `new T[1]` with `new T`. `operator new` and `operator new[]` (and the corresponding deletes) are *replaceable* ([basic.stc.dynamic]/2). A user-defined replacement could detect which one is called, so the as-if rule doesn't allow this replacement.

Note: if the compiler could detect that these functions had not been replaced, it could make that change. But there's nothing in the source code that indicates that the compiler-supplied functions are being replaced. The replacement is generally done at **link** time, simply by linking in the replacement versions (which hide the library-supplied version); that's generally too late for the **compiler** to know about it.

Comment: A better argument would be run-time linking. With LTO, the compiler can see the whole program, except dynamic libraries. If we don't consider dynamic libraries, the compiler can do the replacement, if we compile with LTO.

Answer (score 5):

The rule is simple: `delete[]` must match `new[]` and `delete` must match `new`: the behaviour on using any other combination is undefined.

The compiler is indeed allow to turn `new T[1]` into a simple `new T` (and deal with the `delete[]` appropriately), due to the *as-if* rule. I haven't come across a compiler that does this though.

If you have any reservations about performance, then profile it.

Comment: the question is clearly not about unmatched scalar/array new/delete

Comment: There are very few circumstances in which a compiler could turn `new T[1]` into a simple `new T` - it would have to be able to prove that it has visibility of all corresponding `delete []` expressions. Proving that is a pretty tough ask if the pointer (obtained from the new expression) is ever passed between functions in different compilation units.   Optimisations that rely on significant analysis by the compiler for small benefit don't tend to be implemented.   Except by developers doing premature optimisation.

Comment: @Peter It is sufficient if it knows what the array-delete and object-delete expressions do. Still infeasible in the general case, as the functions are replacable.

Comment: @Deduplicator - The compiler always has information about what the array-delete and object-delete expressions do - and there is more to that than calling the replaceable functions.   But if it is going to change the working of a new-expression in a special case, it would somehow need to change every corresponding delete-expression consistently.